# Literals in Trait methods implementing generics

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn `Generics` and `Traits` in Rust and using the `num` crate to write generic code.
I get the following compiler error

```
6 |         return self.gt(0)
  |                     -- ^ expected type parameter `T`, found integer
```

on this code block.

```
use num::{Integer, zero};

trait CanCompareGreater<T: Integer> {
    fn gt(&self, other: T) -> bool;
    fn is_positive(&self) -> bool {
        return self.gt(0)
    }
}

struct MyNumber {
    num: i32,
}

impl CanCompareGreater<i32> for MyNumber
{
    fn gt(&self, other: i32) -> bool {
        self.num > other
    }
}

fn main() {
    let n = MyNumber {num: 5};
    println!("{}", n.is_positive());
}
```

If I use `num::zero` it works correctly.
But that restricts it to symbols defined in the `num` crate. I want it to work with any integer literal in the trait methods.
How would I go about doing it ?

I've tried `0 as Integer` which doesn't compile `0 as i32` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literal numbers have their own inference going on that's separate from generic inference. This inference can't escape the function or depend on generics, so you can't use it here. You also can't use `as` since that is also not connected to generic inference. But there's the [`NumCast`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.NumCast.html) trait that mimics `as`.

```rs
use num::{Integer, NumCast};

trait CanCompareGreater<T: Integer + NumCast> {
    fn gt(&self, other: T) -> bool;
    fn is_positive(&self) -> bool {
        return self.gt(T::from(4).unwrap())
    }
}
```

There's also [`num_traits::AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) which is closer to `as` since it is infallible.

Comment: Thanks, this helps with what I wanted to do.

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct, except for the (weird) fact that you replaced `0` with `4`...

Comment: @jthulhu I did that because the question was about integers besides zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** drewtato's answer is probably better than mine, as it provides a solution based on [num::NumCast](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.NumCast.html) (a trait I wasn't familiar with). A word of caution though: one needs to be aware that for out-of-range values [`T::from()`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.NumCast.html#tymethod.from) would return `None`. We are not talking about the specific value in `MyNumber`'s instance `num` field, but the value passed as a parameter to `T::from(...)`.

I'll keep my answer below, as it might still be helpful in understanding why the OP's example didn't work.

---

Let's first take a look at this example (which has nothing to do with generics or the [num](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/index.html) crate:

```
fn abc(a: i32) {
    println!("Called abc with {a}");
}

fn main() { 
    let b = 23 as i16;
    abc(b);
}
```

The compiler emits the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |     abc(b);
  |     --- ^ expected `i32`, found `i16`
```

In `CanCompareGreater::is_positive()` you are trying to call the method `gt` by passing some specific value of a specific type (such as `i32`) where a generic `T: Integer` is expected. That cannot be compiled, because `T`'s type might happen to be different from the type of the specific value you are trying to pass, and then you'd get in a situation similar to the above example.

Comment: How would I go about coding what I wanted ?
Basically, a generic method that takes a generic type as input and another trait method (that is implemented in the definition) that calls the above method with a specific value.

Comment: To add to this, `i32` has an impl for `Integer`, so why wouldn't the compiler infer that the value is within the bounds of the generic parameter ?

Comment: You are trying to write a method with a _default implementation_. But I don't think you can pass an arbitrary integer literal. If you passed `555` for example, that wouldn't fit in some of the standard integer types (`u8`, `i8`). If you passed a value between `0` and `127` that should be fine for all _standard_ integer types. But who says `Integer` will only be implemented for the  _standard_ integer types.

Comment: To your second comment: for your `impl CanCompareGreater<i32>` implementation that might be OK, but the default method implementation of `is_positive()` still needs to "work" (compile) for all other potential implementations.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it. If I'm understanding it, basically I'm trying to compare a specific type to all possible types of Integer, which is problematic. The same call such as `n.gt(0)` working in main and not working in the trait def was throwing me off.